# Nested unordered_map / hash_map update in C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I'm new in C++ and have the following problems about unordered_map (or hash_map):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int,int> h1;
    int temp1=0;
    h1.insert(pair<int,int>(0,temp1));
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>> h2;
    h2.insert(pair<int, unordered_map<int,int>>(1,h1));
    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>>::iterator h2_itor=h2.find(1);
    h2_itor->second.find(0)->second++;

    unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>> h3;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        int first=rand()%10;
        int second=rand()%10;

        unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>>::iterator h3_itor=h3.find(first);
        if(h3_itor!=h3.end())
        {
            unordered_map<int,int> submap=h3_itor->second;
            unordered_map<int,int>::iterator submap_itor=submap.find(second);
            if(submap_itor!=submap.end())
                submap_itor->second++;
            else
                submap.insert(pair<int,int>(second, 1));
        }
        else
        {
            unordered_map<int,int> submap;
            submap.insert(pair<int,int>(second,1));
            h3.insert(pair<int, unordered_map<int,int>>(first,submap));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is quite odd. For h1 and h2 it seems work, which means the value in h1 with key 0 is updated (incremented by 1). Though this looks trivial, for h3, which I randomly insert some "pairs" (first, second) and counting with hash map, the count seems can not be updated. For example, it may be like this:

```
insert 1 -> 7 -> 1 
 ... 
now update 1 -> 7 -> 1 to 1 -> 7 -> 2 using my code
fetch: h3.find(1)->second.find(7)->second : it's still 1 but not 2!
```

which shows the update of value is unsuccessful. I know in Java this never happens. So where does this problem lies?

Comment: i'm finding it difficult to follow the logic of the test program. can you reduce the problem to 5 or 6 lines of code?

Comment: @Richard Hodges I've refined the code to make it shorter. The logic of h1 and h2 is inserting h1 into h2 as the value with some (random) key, then trying to update the value of some item in h1 (with h1 itself as an item of h2). The basic idea is to see if a sub-map of a hash map can be updated. (Though it sounds trivial.) The logic of h3 is also a "nested" hash map. I randomly insert some sub-map into it, as well as some random items into these sub-maps, to see if the values can be updated.

Comment: The revised program doesn't try to produce any output, so the expected output (empty) is the same as the actual output (also empty). This is working as intended in my book. Please read about [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
unordered_map<int,int> submap = h3_itor->second;
```

This results in the whole submap being **copied** into you new local `submap` objects. All the modifications you do to it are lost when it gets destroyed upon leaving the scope.

Instead you can use the reference to the actual hashmap element you want to modify:

```
unordered_map<int,int> &submap = h3_itor->second;
```

This one `&` should fix everything.

Comment: Thank you:-). It works. I'm not familiar with the syntax of C++ O.O

Comment: well if you're coming from Java then it can seem weird at first, but I feel like this particular thing (assignment always implies a copy) is more straightforward in c++ and you'll get used to it quite fast. There are other, much more unnatural things to meet:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a refactored version (i think) of the second part of the code. I am also generating a consistent test data set so we can reproduce behaviour on each run (randomness is an anathema to testing).

Here's the code. What's the question?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

using i2i = std::unordered_map<int, int>;
using map_i_to_i2i = std::unordered_map<int, i2i>;

void test_insert(map_i_to_i2i& outer, int v1, int v2)
{
    auto iouter = outer.find(v1);
    if (iouter == outer.end()) {
        std::cout << "case c) [" << v1 << "] = [" << v2 << "] = 1\n";
        outer[v1][v2] = 1;
    }
    else {
        auto& inner = iouter->second;
        auto iinner = inner.find(v2);
        if (iinner == inner.end())
        {
            std::cout << "case b) [" << v1 << "][" << v2 << "] = 1\n";
            inner.emplace_hint(iinner, v2, 1);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "case c) [" << v1 << "][" << v2 << "] += 1\n";
            iinner->second += 1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    map_i_to_i2i h3;
    for (int passes = 0 ; passes < 3 ; ++passes)
    {
        for (int x = 0 ; x < 2 ; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < 2 ; ++y) {
                test_insert(h3, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just an FYI: if this is more than an exercise in using iterators, there is a much easier way to do this:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>> h3
h3[0][0] = 1;

for (int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
    int first=rand()%10;
    int second=rand()%10;
    h3[first][second]++;
}
```

This works because, if a value is missing, [`unordered_map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) will default construct and insert it. For a map, that is an empty map, and for an int, that's zero.

If you wanted another default, you could use [`unordered_map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace), e.g.:

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int,int>> h3
h3[0][0] = 2;

for (int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
    int x=rand()%10;
    int y=rand()%10;
    int& val = h3[x].emplace(y, 1).first->second;
    val *= 2;
}
```

Yes, thats slightly more confusing: `emplace` inserts the specified value if the key is missing (no overwriting if it already exists), and returns `std::pair<iterator, bool>`.

Here, the bool tells you if your value was inserted or not, and iterator itself is a wrapper around `std::pair<key,val>*`, hence the `.first->second` to get the value out.

Besides being shorter/more readable, both of these are also more efficient. In your code, you do a lookup twice if the value isn't present, but both of the above only do one lookup.